# Solve this arithmetic question without algebra

Tags: arithmetic

Dictionary A costs $64$ dollars, while dictionary B costs $54$ dollars. A teacher buys $59$ of the dictionaries altogether for 3426 dollars. How many of each did he/she buy?

64x + 54y = 3426 --- **1**

x + y = 59 --- **2**

Multiply **2** by 54,

54x + 54 y = 3186 --- **3**

**1** - **3**,

10x = 240

x = 24

Sub. x into **2**,

y = 35

I can solve this question with algebra but it is supposed to be solved with simple arithmetic only.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Show that you made an effort and we will be happy to help you.

Comment: Missing data. How much did the teacher pay?

Comment: First, address egreg's comment. The teacher can buy any number of Dictionary A from $0$ to $59$ without violating the information given, so as stated the problem cannot be solved. Evidently you've left off an additional piece of information, which is almost certainly (we've all seen this sort of problem before) the total amount the teacher paid. Now to your question: Algebra is simple math, but done with variables instead of known numbers. So solve the problem with algebra, and it will tell you how to solve it without algebra.

Comment: Thank you @egreg , I have added the information

Comment: Had he baught $59$ B, he would have paid $3426-54\cdot59=240$ less. The difference is explained by 24 $A$.

Answer (score 0):

> Dictionary A costs 64 dollars, while dictionary B costs 54 dollars.

This information provides you with information to calculate the cost:
$$
64 x + 54 y = c \quad (1)
$$

> A teacher buys $59$ of the dictionaries altogether.

This gives you the information relating $x$ and $y$.
$$
  x + y = 59 \quad (2)
$$

Implicitly we have been given the constraints
$$
x, y \in \mathbb{Z} \quad (3)
$$
as we can buy or give only whole books and
$$
x, y \ge 0 \quad (4)
$$
as we buy only.

> How many of each did he/she buy?

Let us have a look at the information in a graphical way:

[image: underspecified]

The $x$-axis features the $x$-values, the $y$-axis the $y$-values.

The light blue areas are the half planes $x \ge 0$ and $y >0$.
The red line $f$ represents all real values satisfying equation $(2)$.

Together with the constraints $(3)$ and $(4)$ all feasible solutions $(x, y)$ lie on the green line segment between $A=(0,59)$ and $B=(59,0)$. (We can not see the discrete gaps due to the scale of the image)

We see that this problem seems to allow many solutions:
$$
X = \{ (0, 59), (1, 58), (2, 57), (3, 56), \dotsc, (58, 1), (59, 0) \}
$$

As Paul Sinclair wrote in the comments, it is likely a piece of information is missing. The total cost $c$.

The image features the yellow line $g$, which stands for $c = 1442$ and equation $(1)$. 
The image suggests there is no intersection between $g$ and the line segment $AB$. So this $c$ was not a good choice.

Actually the task implicitly states that a sale happened.

So we now could check what $c$ values, which are likely to satisfy $c > 0$ and $c \in \mathbf{Z}$, intersect the set of feasible solutions on $AB$?

The other choices for $c$ each result in a line parallel to the yellow line $g$.

An intersection means a solution to
$$
64 x + 54 y = c \\
x + y = 59
$$
which gives:
$$
y = 59 - x \\
c = 64 x + 54 (59 - x) = 10 x + 3186
$$

So all $60$ solutions are possible, each having a different total cost between $3186$ and $3776$.